# Could not find argument in nested Prisma / GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, prisma

In my `graphql-yoga` server I have a schema like this:

```
type Play {
  id: ID!
  frames: [Frame!]!
}

type Frame {
  id: ID!
  play: Play!
}

query  {
  play(playId: "myid") {
    id
    ### The error occurs when I uncomment these lines:
    # frames {
    #   id
    # }
  }
}
```

I have resolvers for the query:

```
return await context.prisma.play({ id: args.playId })
```

I also have resolvers for the relationships, e.g.:

```
const frames = async (root, args, context) => {
  return await context.prisma.frames({ play: { id: root.id }})
}
```

When I run the query with the lines commented out it executes as expected. When I add in the relationship I get an error:

```
Error: Could not find argument play for type Frame
    at server\node_modules\prisma-client-lib\dist\Client.js:248:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at server\node_modules\prisma-client-lib\dist\Client.js:234:50
    at Array.reduceRight (<anonymous>)
    at Client.generateSelections (server\node_modules\prisma-client-lib\dist\Client.js:231:32)
    at Client.<anonymous> (server\node_modules\prisma-client-lib\dist\Client.js:87:35)
    at step (server\node_modules\prisma-client-lib\dist\Client.js:47:23)
    at Object.next (server\node_modules\prisma-client-lib\dist\Client.js:28:53)
    at server\node_modules\prisma-client-lib\dist\Client.js:22:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

I'm using `prisma-client-lib@1.18.1`, `graphql-yoga@1.16.2` and `graphql@0.13.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that this error was in the resolver, although the stack trace was unhelpful. I changed

```
const frames = async (root, args, context) => {
  return await context.prisma.frames({ play: { id: root.id }})
}
```

To

```
const frames = async (root, args, context) => {
  return await context.prisma.frames({ where: { play: { id: args.playId }}})
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what was breaking for me too - thanks for the answer!